# How to convert from european style time to us style using python and xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I have a set of temperatures that are of the form '22,4' rather than '22.4'. I am new to Python (just started a few days ago) and am writing a program to transform csv files to xlsx files and graph some of the data.

The file is originally delimited with semi-colons. Currently, I have adapted a set of nested for loops to write the xlsx file, but the temperature data is as described above.

```
def graph_file():
    workbook = xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook("New File.xlsx", {'strings_to_numbers': True})
    for file in files:
        sheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Sheet1")
        with open(file) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
            for r, row in enumerate(reader):
                for c, val in enumerate(row):
                    one_plus = r + 1
                    sheet.write(r, c, val)
                    sheet.write("AZ1", "Time")
                    sheet.write("AR1", "Temperature")
                    sheet.write("AZ" + str(one_plus), str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=r)))
                    sheet.write('AT' + str(one_plus), '=NUMBERVALUE(AQ' + str(one_plus) + ', ",", ".")')
```

Here is what I have now which would work, but Excel keeps adding an @ sign to the front of my formula and I get a #NAME? error.

[image: screenshot of the excel page]

Is there a better way to do this or does anyone have a quick fix for the excel problem that I can add to my code? thanks

Comment: In the CSV file are the numbers using comma or full stop/period as the decimal point?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach, when reading using a `csv.reader()` everything would be a string, you could convert these to numbers as needed:

```
def graph_file():
    workbook = xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook("New File.xlsx", {'strings_to_numbers': True})
    
    for file in files:
        sheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Sheet1")
        sheet.write("AZ1", "Time")
        sheet.write("AR1", "Temperature")
        
        with open(file) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
            
            for r, row in enumerate(reader):
                print(row)

                for c, val in enumerate(row):
                    if r > 0:
                        if ',' in val:
                            val = float(val.replace(',', '.'))
                        else:
                            val = int(val)
                        
                    one_plus = r + 1
                    sheet.write(r, c, val)
                    sheet.write("AZ" + str(one_plus), str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=r)))
                    sheet.write('AT' + str(one_plus), '=NUMBERVALUE(AQ' + str(one_plus) + ', ",", ".")')
                    
        workbook.close()
```

This ignores the header row and then converts any value to an integer. If a comma is seen, it replaces it with a period and converts the string to a float.

The `=NUMBERVALUE()` should then not be needed.

I would move your `AZ1` and `AR1` writes outside your loop as they do not change.